# Listener Android

Tags: android

Интерес располагается к схеме работы слушателя через сетевое соединение для какой нибудь базы данных, например, имеются службы в которых всё это реализовывается,
к примеру в вашем телефоне приложение вконтакте, viber, whatsapp и подобные. Происходят моментальные уведомления об сообщениях и моментальный вывод.

То есть, по большому счёту приложение слушает базу данных, таблицу, ту что нужно, подсчитывает кол-во сообщений и т.д Непосредственно через API.
Всё это, происходит в реальном времени.

Кто может мне подсказать в каком направлении идти, создавать отдельный поток и рекурсивно проверять базу? Или сделать какой нибудь хитрый слушатель, правда я ещё не уверен в этом, хотя рекурсивный метод дорого стоит, кто сталкивался с подобным на практике?

Comment: то, что Вы описываете - называется [push notification](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Сервер может послать клиенту короткое "сообщение". Думайте о этом как о смс через tcp.

А вот как сервер решит, что нужно это сообщение слать клиенту - это дело сервера. Клиенту не нужно знать внутреннее устройство Вашей базы.

Почему так? А представьте, что тысячи клиентов ломануться сканировать и проверять Вашу базу. Жить она будет не долго. А так - сервер раз в минуту собрал свеженькое и разослал.

Comment: То есть получается 
- сервер с базой данных хранит данные.
- его дёргает Облако сообщений. В результате отправляет уведомление.
- устройство принимает сигнал, пока ещё мне не ясно по какому принципу
- после сигнала, выполняет действие по считыванию новых данных из сервера с базой данных, и выводит последнее сообщение?

Comment: сервер сам дергает "облако сообщений". "Сигнал" устройство получает по обычному tcp/ip. А получив "сигнал", устройство делает то, что ему нужно. В самом "сигнале" (пуш-сообщении) уже может быть достаточно данных.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь есть 2 варианта:

1. Через [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) механизм описанный [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim). Кроме очевидных плюсов описанных [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) метод имеет один существенный минус - вы должны иметь доступ к серверу для реализации доступа из сервера к облаку Google, что не всегда возможно.
2. Более кондовый способ: "дерганье" собственно самого сервера непосредственно из вашей аппы. Механизм обычно устраивается так:

   а) Фоновый поток/сервис, который с заданным интервалом "дергает" сервер и результаты пишет в локальную БД

   б) Над БД устраивается [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html), далее сверх `ContentProvider`'а уже можно устроить [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) с соответствующим [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)

   в) Завершающий штрих `CursorAdapter` может иметь слушателя [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html), который вы и будете ловить на предмет изменений в локальной базе, следовательно и на сервере.

P.S. Это вам не ПЖИВ-ПЖИВ орать на площадях :)

Comment: у кондового способа есть пара сильных минусов. 

 - сильнее садиться батарея.
 - "интервал дерганья" нужно угадать. Слишком часто - больше нагрузка, слишком редко - больше "тормознутости". Можно и висящими соединениями сделать, но там тоже есть свои минусы и плюсы.

Comment: Спасибо парни )